# Change between iframes with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with links (every link is a .html file) that targets to an iframe. I want to the content (links) of that iframe changes between each other in a "smooth way" when I click any of those links on the menu. All of this happens in the same index.html, only the iframe on the index changes.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please refer to [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide details. Also if menu is outside iFrames, you just have to update source and it should work.

Comment: Its not clear why having nearly duplicate `index1.html, index2.html, index3.html` files doesn't work in a smooth way.  Can we see your JS fiddle?

Comment: No, I only have one index.html. I don't have a js file yet.